# Any free servers to integrate VoIp feature in android?

Tags: android, call, voip, system-calls

I need to develop an android app by which i can make call to any mobile phones/landlines. Is there any free SIP servers and SIP clients to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

[LinPhone](http://www.linphone.org/) provides open source SIP clients.

They also have a number of server parts, but it's unclear if you mean free as in beer - in general making free phone calls to real physical mobile/landlines is not possible, someone somewhere has to pay the charge!